# Is there a more efficient way than this to load records associated with records in a list?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, performance

I have a model Playlist, and a model User, both of which have_many of each other, through a join model PlaylistUser.

On my `playlists#show` action, I want to print a list of all of a Playlist's Users, along with the first two Playlists associated with each of those Users.

Right now here's what I have:

**playlists/show.html.erb**

```
<% @playlist = Playlist.find(params[:id]) %>
<% @playlist.users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.name %>
  <%= user.playlists.first.name %>
  <%= user.playlists.second.name %>
<% end %>
```

**models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlist_users
  has_many :playlists, :through => :playlist_users
end

class PlaylistUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :playlist
  belongs_to :user
end

class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlist_users
  has_many :users, :through => :playlist_users
end
```

But there is an enormous change in performance when I delete the `user.playlists` lines and print out only the `user.name`, because then the database only has to make one query, as opposed to hundreds.

Does anyone know of a way to make this more efficient? Maybe I could somehow load all the associated Playlists in the original query?

Comment: Besides spickermann's answer, see N + 1 queries problem: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`includes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) method to tell Rails to preload associated records with just one query upfront.

Loading from the database is a controller responsibility and should not happen in the view. Therefore, add the following to your controller:

```
playlist = Playlist.find(params[:id])
@users = playlist.users.includes(:playlists)
```

And change your view to just iterate over the users array:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.name %>
  <%= user.playlists.first.name %>
  <%= user.playlists.second.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is there a way to order the included table in the original query? For example, if I wanted to order `user.playlists` by `order(:song_count)`.